# Mac OS + VS Code: Why does Console.Write("X") method write nothing into console?

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio-code

Mac OS (v12.6)
VS Code (v1.72.0)
dotnet v6.0.401

Simple code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
{
    Console.WriteLine("X");
    // Console.Write("X");
}
```

Result:
[image]

Good! I see console output.

Ok. Now I try to do the same but with `Console.Write` method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
{
    //Console.WriteLine("X");
    Console.Write("X");
}
```

Result:
[image]

I see nothing now...

Why does `Console.Write("X")` method write nothing? How can I solve the problem?

P.S. `Console.Out.Flush();` doesn't help.
P.S.2. If I add `Console.WriteLine();` code line after my loop then I get the expected output (*thanks to @jmcilhinney*). But why I am to add it?

Comment: If you put a `WriteLine` after the loop, do you see the result of all those `Write` calls then?

Comment: @jmcilhinney yes, it helps to me. Thank you! But why does it happen? I don't like the "black boxes"...

Comment: Try it in a "real" console. Maybe the VS Code terminal is behaving weird.

Comment: @Ray you are right: it works fine in "real" console. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this is probably in the dotnet/sdk Git Repository at the link below.

https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/5928#issuecomment-215895840

Comment from the GIT Repo

> This is because our StreamForwarder that takes output from the real process and forwards it to the process running dotnet run only writes when it hits a newline:

Code that waits for the flush

```
  while ((readCharacterCount = reader.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) > 0)
        {
            currentCharacter = buffer[0];

            if (currentCharacter == s_flushBuilderCharacter)
            {
                WriteBuilder();
            }
            else if (! s_ignoreCharacters.Contains(currentCharacter))
            {
                _builder.Append(currentCharacter);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `Console.Write();` appends to whatever hasn't been flushed to the console yet. `Console.WriteLine();` is required to flush to the console.

This code:

```cs
Console.Write("x");
Console.Write("y");
Console.Write("z");
Console.WriteLine();
```

Will produce: "xyz" in the Console

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.write?view=net-6.0